# How do I bake particle UV's at end of simulation in Molecular Script Add-on

Tags: uv, particles, baking

Is there any way to bake the texture at a certain frame onto particles so it looks like they all formed percectly into an image? I've seen it before but I can't find how to do it anywhere.

[image: Camera]

[image: Camera]

[image: Location]

[image: Loacation]

[image: Velocity[![][6]]][7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOcSb.gif)
I've tried all these settings and re-baked nothing happens.